# How do I get the command line option for my Win32 C/C++ program?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I have a C/C++ winapi program that I'd like to extend a command line functionality to (which I've seen done in C#, but never C++). If the executable is opened with no arguments, it opens the window as normal, but when called from a command line with arguments such as an input or output file, the window does not open and all user interaction is done through the command line. How could I accomplish this? Preferably I'd like to be able to do it in C, as that's where my WinMain() function is.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `LPSTR lpCmdLine` parameter in `WinMain`. You can use `CommandLineToArgvW` function to parse `lpCmdLine`. When necessary parameters exist, you will not create or show program window and do the job.

Comment: Just looked up the docs. How can I determine the number of command line arguments to pass to `CommandLineToArgvW` as `pNumArgs`?
EDIT: Never mind, it's a pointer to what will be ASSIGNED the number of args. Thank you so much!

Comment: `CommandLineToArgvW` is helper function. You can analyze `lpCmdLine` directly with loop especially if you expect only 1 argument. `CommandLineToArgvW` is good to parse e.g. long file names with spaces enclosed with quotes.

Comment: Note: when using `CommandLineToArgvW()`, it is better to use `GetCommandLineW()` to ensure a Unicode string, instead of the `lpCmdLine` parameter of `WinMain()` which is not a Unicode string.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can get the (parsed) command line arguments passed to your application.

#### Entry point

The CRT passes the command line into the user-provided entry point ([WinMain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/winmain--the-application-entry-point)) as the third argument. Depending on whether your application is compiled for Unicode or not this is either a wide character string or a narrow character string. Using the narrow character version cannot be guaranteed to work when accepting input you do not control. The command line is accepting input you do not control, so you must compile for Unicode (by defining the `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` preprocessor symbols).

Either way, the command line is passed as a single character string. As such it is of limited utility unless you parse out the individual arguments.

#### Using the Windows API

The Windows API provides the [GetCommandLineW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-getcommandlinew) function that allows you get a pointer to the command line at any point in your program. Again, this only returns a single character string. The string can be parsed into individual arguments by calling [CommandLineToArgvW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-commandlinetoargvw), producing both an array of arguments as well as its size. Take note that there is no narrow character version of `CommandLineToArgvW`, so you cannot apply it to the command line argument passed into `WinMain` if you aren't compiling for Unicode.

Regardless, both of these API calls are available even if you aren't compiling for Unicode.

#### CRT

If you don't care about portability, Microsoft's CRT implementation provides the [__argc, __argv, __wargv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/argc-argv-wargv) global variables, that can be used anywhere in your program to get the parsed command line. While convenient, it depends on the preprocessor symbols defined whether `__wargv` stores a valid pointer. It only does if `_UNICODE` is defined.